# AnguarlJS Routing, Controller not executing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but I can't get my controller to execute the console only shows router running even though I am running #/

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log('MainController Running');
    $scope.test = 'This is a test';
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        console.log('Router Running')
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                template: "{{test}}",
                controller: 'MainController'
            });
    }
]);
```

HTML file

```
<div class="container" data-ng-app="app">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div date-ng-view style="border:1px solid red;height:50px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What {{test}} means? You should specify a template html file there and date-ng-view is misstyped, shoud be data- not date-

Comment: @fals...not true, can be any html or expression. You are thinking of templateUrl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup looks fine. Looks like a minor typo in your markup. Observe the following...

```
<div date-ng-view>
```

=>

```
<div data-ng-view>
```

Comment: Haha, Thanks!! I wasted an hour on this.